# Simple TCP client - memory issues

Tags: haskell, memory-management, networking

Does this snippet take too much memory? How can I let the connection opened with the function `connectTo` outside the forever loop?

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Network
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment

main = do 
    [host,port]<-getArgs
    let pn1 = fromIntegral ( read port::Int)
    forever $ do
        h <- connectTo host $ PortNumber pn1
        hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
        getLine >>= hPutStrLn h 
        forkIO $ hGetContents h >>= putStrL
```

If I put the line `forever ...` after the line `hSetBuffering`, the connection is lost after one input.

It seems to me that this code open too much connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`hGetContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3ahGetContents) gets *all* remaining input, using lazy IO.  The second call to `hGetContents` throws an error because the first call has already claimed the data, in a sense.

What I would do is have a separate thread tunnel data from the handle to standard output, and have the main thread tunnel data from standard input to the handle:

```
_ <- forkIO $ hGetContents h >>= putStr
getContents >>= hPutStr h
```

I would also use `LineBuffering` rather than `NoBuffering`, so it doesn't have to transmit a TCP packet for every character (*).

Thus, we have:

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Network
import System.Environment
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    [host, port] <- getArgs
    h <- connectTo host $ PortNumber $ toEnum $ read port
    hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
    hSetBuffering h      LineBuffering
    _ <- forkIO $ hGetContents h >>= putStr
    getContents >>= hPutStr h
```

A couple notes:

- I was able to avoid the type signature by using `toEnum` rather than `fromIntegral`.
- `_ <- forkIO $ ...` suppresses a warning when the program is compiled with `-Wall`.

We can do better, though.  Currently, if the server disconnects, the user does not see that the server disconnected until hitting enter a couple times, which produces an ugly error message:

```
tcp-client: <socket: 3>: commitBuffer: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
```

Let's see if we can get the program to terminate when either the server or the client closes the connection.  Bear in mind that:

- `getContents` and `hGetContents` terminate the list when EOF is reached.  Thus:

  - `hGetContents h >>= putStr` terminates when the server closes the connection
  - `getContents >>= hPutStr h` terminates when the user presses <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>
- The program terminates when the main thread terminates, regardless if child threads still have work to do.

A good way to do this, I think, is to perform the receiving and sending in two separate threads, and have the main thread wait on an MVar:

```
done <- newEmptyMVar

_ <- forkIO $ (hGetContents h >>= putStr)
              `finally` tryPutMVar done ()

_ <- forkIO $ (getContents >>= hPutStr h)
              `finally` tryPutMVar done ()

-- Wait for at least one of the above threads to complete
takeMVar done
```

<sub>* Actually, sending individual characters at a time will probably trigger [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).  Still, sending characters one at a time creates a lot of unnecessary CPU overhead.</sub>

Comment: in order to better understand your comment i will try with a tcp simple server . I have found one here or in stackoverflow but can't find it again. Once i have some more code to share i will post it again.